# PGFplots axis ticks numbers format

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to know how could I exclude `0` of this axis format

`yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci zerofill,precision=1}`

In order to avoid this.

[image]

the most similar what I've got is using this code (as MWE)

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major, scaled ticks=false,scale=2.2, y post scale=2, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, 1000 sep={\;}}]
\addplot+[
        only marks,
        mark=+,
        color=NavyBlue,
        error bars/.cd,
        x dir=both, x explicit,
        y dir=both, y explicit,
        ]
        table[y error=yerror,x error=xerror]
            {NmP3pgf1.dat};
\addplot[
        red,
        domain=-3:1
        ] {-120322.13*x + 53246.18};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{pgfplots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this

[image]

being this NmP3pgf1.dat

```
x           y                xerror       yerror  label
0.00        52080.65         0.01         648.31   a
-0.80       148381.84        0.01       2618.50   a
-2.80       391752.88        0.01       9554.95   a
```

Comment: There are a few `0` floating around, which do you mean?

Comment: I would like that `0.0·10⁰` be a simple `0` but keep that format for rest ticks.

Comment: Does [Jake's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136944/106162) to [Pgfplots: tick labels with zerofill except for 0 tick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136937/106162) work for you?

Comment: I get a `! Dimension too large` error message. But apparently that would be the solution, right.

Comment: Hum, can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Regarding `Dimension too large`, hard to say without further information, but maybe [pgfplots “Dimension too large” returned when plotting rational function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167918/110998), [Dimension too large while plotting with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13838/110998) or [pgfplots: dimension too large when reading data from file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129186/110998) helps.

Comment: do you mean something like `yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick == 0?int(1):int(0)}\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0....\else 0\fi}` @percusse ?

Comment: posted an answer instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially Jake's solution is correct as usual but here your numbers are too big for the `\ifdim` test. Hence a bit more lower level pgf number formatting is needed.

If you just use the following it will perform a test for zero and execute the correct branch of the if.

```
yticklabel={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
    \pgfmathparse{\tick}%
    \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{0}{0}{%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=1]{\tick}%
    }%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
}
```

[image]